Finding $\delta$ for convergence of $f(x)=x^3+2x^2-3x-1$ at its approximate root.
I've had some exposure to elementary analysis and I am currently going through a problem in numerical analysis involving finding roots using Newton's method. The algorithm has convergence issues which raises the question about what appropriate $\delta$ I need to guarantee convergence. The function is
$$f(x)=x^3+2x^2-3x-1$$
The root I am focusing on is approximately $x=1.1986912435$. My issue is working with this approximation to find the delta. Here's what I tried. Since I "know" the root, I can rewrite the polynomial as
$$x^3+2x^2-3x-1\approx (x-1.1986912435)(x^2+3.1986912435x+0.834243184244)$$
where I get the approximate values for the second order polynomial by solving
$$x^3+2x^2-3x-1=(x-c)(x^2+ax+b)=(x-c)\left(x^2+(2+c)x+(2+c)c-3\right)$$
From here, I do the inequality analysis as follows:
$$|x^3+2x^2-3x-1|\approx |(x-1.1986912435)(x^2+3.1986912435x+0.834243184244)|$$
$$=|x-1.1986912435||x^2+3.1986912435x+0.834243184244|$$
From here, I pick a delta to bound the second order polynomial. I pick $\delta=1$. This bounds the second order polynomial by $|x^2+3.1986912435x+0.834243184244|\leq 13$. So,
taking $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{13}\right\}$, $f(x)$ is guaranteed to converge to zero.
The fact that I had to work with an approximation value is what makes me nervous. If anyone can validate what I did or show me a better way for finding deltas for this kind of problem, it would be very much appreciated.

Would you like to explain what do you exactly mean by "the $\delta$"?

Why not to use Newton method for each root ?

You are better off using Newton's method. since the root is in the interval $[1.1, 1.2]$ and the convergence conditions for Newton's method hold in that interval, for $x_0 \in I = [1.1, 1.2]$, you know that
$$
|x_n - z| \leq K |x_{n-1}-z|^2, 
$$
where $z$ is the root, $x_0$ is the initial approximation and $K = \frac{\max|f''|}{2 \min |f'|}$. This way you can get the simple bound
$$
|x_{n}-z| \leq \frac 1K (K|1.2-1.1)^{2^n} \leq 0.899 \times (0.112)^{2^n}
$$
so, with only 4 iterations of Newton's method we are getting the "exact" solution, up to machine precision.
